Cast a shadow on plane with ocean modifier while preserving high transmission and low roughness
Using Cycles. The HDRI I'm using has a strong light source hitting my scene. I set up a plane with an Ocean modifier, but the model is not casting any shadow produced on the plane (only reflection).

Roughness is about 0, and Transmission Weight is 1 in material settings. This makes the plane look "watery", which is the intended look.
Now, if I increase the Roughness value to anything close to 0.5, it obviously produces a strong shadow on the plane, but some water realism is lost.

Also, the nodes used for the plane are the just regular Princpled BSDF and the Material Output ones. For now, I'm not concerned about animation, it will be just a static shot. The HDRI image is somewhat trivial, I'm only using this one for demonstrative purposes.
But what else is needed here, so that I can get a proper shadow cast by the model, similar to this photo? TIA.
edit: some more examples here, here and here.
edit2: marked as solved after following @Lutzi's recommendations. Final render that comes as close as what I had in mind:


You can't have a perfectly smooth surface and shadows on it. Imagine your ocean is perfectly flat mirror, there wouldn't be any shadows, just the reflections. Shadows are a property of diffuse surfaces in some sense.


In the image you linked, the shot is perfectly vertical, thus minimizing the reflections. So the shadow also appears stronger than in your shot.
There could be 2 ways for water to generate shadows : imperfections on the surface, and volumetric shadows under the surface.
For imperfections, you can use the Sheen settings. It's not perfect but it works and probably can look great with more work.
For volumetrics, you can use a Volume Scatter in addition. Note that you have to change the alpha to be able to see the volume shader. Also, the mesh need to have volume, not a plane.
Here is an example. I'm not good at shading, so there may be better ways to do it :

In this example, the shadow comes mainly from the sheen. Volumetrics are just increasing the effect a bit.

I beg to differ a little on your first statement. I added a few more examples of the phenomenon I want to replicate. As for Sheen, it kinda gives the same result, but I can produce at least some shadow. So, the Volume Scatter seems the way to go for now, that's the effect I'm going after, and of course it makes a lot more sense than just a simple plane. Thank you Lutzi. :D

I assure you, asking for shadows for perfectly smooth surface makes no sense. Your examples come from real life, so not reflective-only and there are imperfections for sure. I'm glad if my answer helped you :)
